# Figure and table numbers are missing a period

Tags: tables, labels, includegraphics, ref

I am writing a science dissertation in the `memoir` class. The numbering system of the figures and tables appears to use the `Chapter` `Figure number in chapter` format, but does not include any separator between `Chapter` and `Figure number in chapter`.

This results in code like `galaxies in figure \ref{fig:mo_2.7}.`, in reference to the first figure in the document, producing[image: SDSS galaxies in figure 11]

This reads like "figure eleven" (11) instead of "figure one point one" (1.1), as I would expect the figure reference package to produce. The same glitch is happening in the caption beneath the actual figure. So, again for the first figure of the document, code that reads

```
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{literature_comparisons/Mo2010_fig_2_27_right.png}
\caption[Galaxies in the SDSS]{The colour–magnitude\index{galaxy colour} relation of about 365,000 galaxies in the SDSS\index{SDSS} (see section \ref{bimodality} for discussion).
}
    \label{fig:mo_2.7}
\end{figure}
```

produces the following text upon compilation with pdflatex:

[image: Figure 11. The colour-magnitude relation of about 365,000 galaxies in the SDSS (see section 1.2.1 for discussion).]

As you can see, references to section labels work fine with chapter, section and subsection numbers all separarated by periods. References to figure and table labels, however, are all missing periods. To illustrate how this numbering looks throughout the document, see the list of figures that latex generates:
[image: List of figures, showing 6 enteries numbered 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, and 31]

The document does not have 31 figures, but does have three chapters that include figures.

The preamble for this dissertation is

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=138mm,top=35mm,bottom=35mm,bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}
\include{content/acronyms}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure})}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\nonzeroparskip
\newsubfloat{figure}
\newcommand{\thesisTitle}{Alpha Omega}
\newcommand{\thesisSubtitle}{}
\newcommand{\thesisName}{AA BB}
\newcommand{\thesisDate}{\today}
\newcommand{\thesisFirstSupervisor}{XX YY}
\newcommand{\thesisSecondSupervisor}{YY ZZ}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversity}{\protect{XX U}}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityDepartment}{Department of X}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityInstitute}{Institute X}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityCity}{Cityname}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityStreetAddress}{XX Road}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityPostalCode}{XXXXX}
\renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{Appendix\space}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\chapterstyle{madsen}
\DoubleSpacing
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\nobibliography*
\makepagestyle{myruled}
\makeheadrule {myruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule {myruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
\makeevenhead {myruled}{}{\small\itshape\leftmark}{}
\makeoddhead {myruled}{}{\small\itshape\rightmark}{}
\makeevenfoot {myruled}{\small \thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot {myruled}{}{}{\small \thepage}

\makepsmarks {myruled}{
\nouppercaseheads
\createmark {chapter} {both} {shownumber}{}{. \ }
\createmark {section} {both}{shownumber}{} {. \ }
\createmark {subsection} {both}{shownumber}{} {. \ }
\createmark {subsubsection}{both}{shownumber}{} {. \ }
\createplainmark {toc} {both} {\contentsname}
\createplainmark {lof} {both} {\listfigurename}
\createplainmark {lot} {both} {\listtablename}
\createplainmark {bib} {both} {\bibname}
\createplainmark {index} {both} {\indexname}
\createplainmark {glossary} {both} {\glossaryname}
}

\makepagestyle{plain}
\makefootrule {plain}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
\makeevenfoot {plain}{\small \thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot {plain}{}{}{\small \thepage}
\makeindex

\makepsmarks {plain}{
\nouppercaseheads
\createmark {chapter} {both} {shownumber}{}{. \ }
\createmark {section} {both}{shownumber}{} {. \ }
\createmark {subsection} {both}{shownumber}{} {. \ }
\createmark {subsubsection}{both}{shownumber}{} {. \ }
\createplainmark {toc} {both} {\contentsname}
\createplainmark {lof} {both} {\listfigurename}
\createplainmark {lot} {both} {\listtablename}
\createplainmark {bib} {both} {\bibname}
\createplainmark {index} {both} {\indexname}
\createplainmark {glossary} {both} {\glossaryname}
}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\pagestyle{myruled}
\makeindex
```

How can I get latex to add periods to figure and table labels and references?

---

Edit:

After a discussion in the comments, I show a minimal example that reproduces the problem and a fix that addresses it. The minimal example is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{plot.png}
\caption{Plot}
\label{fig:plot}
\end{figure}

See figure \ref{fig:plot}.

\end{document}
```

Replacing

```
\mainmatter
```

with

```
\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
```

fixes the problem on the surface level, and the figure numbering system now includes a period between `Chapter` and `Figure number in the chapter`:

[image: Screenshot that reads "See figure one point one".]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Strange… What you want it the default, normally. Try `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}` in your preamble.

Comment: @Bernard Tried adding ```\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}``` in several parts of the preamble. Does not seem to produce any change.

Comment: And with `\AtBeginDocument{...}`?

Comment: @Bernard ```\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}}``` and ```\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter{. }\arabic{figure}}}``` and ```\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter{. \}\arabic{figure}}}``` don't seem to help.

Comment: You should post a minimal, but complete code reproducing the problem. I don't think it's the standard behaviour in the `memoir` class.

Comment: @Bernard's initial suggestion works if after ```\begin{document}```. The minimal example that reproduces the problem: ```\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{plot.png}
\caption{Plot}
\label{fig:plot}
\end{figure}
See figure \ref{fig:plot}.
\end{document}```. Replacing```\mainmatter``` with ```\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}``` fixes the problem.

Comment: I tried your code after I had added some document content. Various problems were reported related to your code. In the LoF numbers looked like 2.1 In the caption as 2.1. and in a `\ref` as 2.1. Basically the `caption` package does not work well with `memoir`.

Comment: This is a known error, please make sure to update your LaTeX installation. At one point the counter resetting macros was added to the LaTeX kernel, but they did so with an errror. This error have long since been fixed.

Comment: @PeterWilson I don't think the caption package messes with counter formatting, and it works fine with memoir has for years. See my other comment on my guess as to the problem.

Comment: @parallelogram do you mind posting the log file from your system that corresponds to the MWE you show, plus information on exactly which LaTeX installation is used.

Comment: @daleif Using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) I've posted the log file on pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/2FNKF9BT

Comment: You should have updated your TeXLive 2018 while you could. The bug was fixed on 2018-04-22, your LaTeX format is dated `LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2`. So you should update, sadly this probably means to need to reinstall to TeXLive 2019 as you can no longer update texlive 2018.

Comment: adding the `\renewcommand` under the `\mainmatter` solved my problem. Thanks!